# Splitting Iterator<(A,B)> into Iterator<A> and Iterator<B>

Tags: rust

I would like to split the output of an object that implements `Iterator<(A,B)>` into two objects that implement `Iterator<A>` and `Iterator<B>`. Since one of the outputs could be iterated more than the other, I'll need to buffer up the output of the `Iterator<(A,B)>` (because I can't rely on the `Iterator<(A,B)>` being cloneable.) The problem is that the iterator could be infinite, so I can't simply collect the output of the iterator into two buffers and return iterators over the two buffers.

So it seems that I'll need to hold buffers of the `A` and `B` objects, and whenever one of the buffers is empty I'll fill it with samples from the `Iterator<(A,B)>` object. This means that I'll need two iterable structs that have mutable references to the input iterator (since both of them will need to call `next()` on the input to fill up the buffers), which is impossible.

So, is there any way to accomplish this in a safe way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible. As you identified you need mutable references to the base iterator from both handles, which is possible using [a type with "internal mutability"](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/std/cell/), that is, one that uses `unsafe` code internally to expose a safe API for acquiring a `&mut` to aliasable data (i.e. contained in a `&`) by dynamically enforcing the invariants that the compiler normally enforces at compile time outside `unsafe`.

I'm assuming you're happy to keep the two iterators on a single thread<sup>1</sup>, so, in this case, we want a [`RefCell`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html). We also need to be able to have access to the `RefCell` from the two handles, entailing storing either a `&RefCell<...>` or an `Rc<RefCell<...>>`. The former would be too restrictive, as it would only allow us to use the pair of iterators in and below the stack frame in which the `RefCell` is created, while we want to be able to freely pass the iterators around, so [`Rc`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/index.html) it is.

In summary, we're basically going to be storing an `Rc<RefCell<Iterator<(A,B)>>>`, there's just the question of buffering. The right tool for the job here is a [`RingBuf`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.RingBuf.html) since we want efficient push/pop at the front and back. Thus, the thing we're sharing (i.e. inside the `RefCell`) could look like:

```
struct SharedInner<A, B, It> {
    iter: It,
    first: RingBuf<A>,
    second: RingBuf<B>,
}
```

We can abbreviate the type actually being shared as `type Shared<A, B, It> = Rc<RefCell<SharedInner<A, B, It>>>;`, which allows us to define the iterators:

```
struct First<A, B, It> {
    data: Shared<A, B, It>
}
impl Iterator<A> for First<A,B,It> {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<A> {
        // ...
    }
}
```

To implement `next` the first thing to do is get a `&mut` to the `SharedInner`, via `self.data.borrow_mut();`. And then get an element out of it: check the right buffer, or otherwise get a new element from `iter` (remembering to buffer the left-over `B`):

```
let mut inner = self.data.borrow_mut();

inner.first.pop_front().or_else(|| {
    inner.iter.next().map(|(a,b)| {
        inner.second.push(b);
        a
    })
})
```

Docs: [`RingBuf.pop_front`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.RingBuf.html#method.pop_front), [`Option.or_else`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/core/option/type.Option.html#method.or_else).

The iterator for the other side is similar. In total:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::collections::{Deque, RingBuf};
use std::rc::Rc;

struct SharedInner<A, B, It> {
    iter: It,
    first: RingBuf<A>,
    second: RingBuf<B>
}

type Shared<A, B, It> = Rc<RefCell<SharedInner<A, B, It>>>;

struct First<A, B, It> {
    data: Shared<A, B, It>
}

impl<A,B, It: Iterator<(A,B)>> Iterator<A> for First<A, B, It> {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<A> {
        let mut inner = self.data.borrow_mut();

        // try to get one from the stored data
        inner.first.pop_front().or_else(|| 
            // nothing stored, we need a new element.
            inner.iter.next().map(|(a, b)| {
                inner.second.push(b);
                a
            }))
    }
}

struct Second<A, B, It> {
    data: Shared<A, B, It>
}
impl<A,B, It: Iterator<(A,B)>> Iterator<B> for Second<A,B,It> {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<B> {
        let mut inner = self.data.borrow_mut();

        inner.second.pop_front().or_else(|| {
            inner.iter.next().map(|(a, b)| {
                inner.first.push(a);
                b
            })
        })
    }
}

fn split<A, B, It: Iterator<(A,B)>>(it: It) -> (First<A, B, It>, 
                                                Second<A, B, It>) {
    let data = Rc::new(RefCell::new(SharedInner { 
        iter: it,
        first: RingBuf::new(),
        second: RingBuf::new(),
    }));

    (First { data: data.clone() }, Second { data: data })
}

fn main() {
    let pairs = range(1u32, 10 + 1).map(|x| (x, 1.0 / x as f64));

    let (mut first, mut second) = split(pairs);

    println!("first:");
    for x in first.by_ref().take(3) {
        println!("  {}", x);
    }

    println!("second:");
    for y in second.by_ref().take(5) {
        if y < 0.2 { break }
        println!("  {}", y);
    }

    let a = first.collect::<Vec<u32>>();
    let b = second.collect::<Vec<f64>>();

    println!("a {}\nb {}", a, b);
}
```

which prints

```
first:
  1
  2
  3
second:
  1
  0.5
  0.333333
  0.25
  0.2
a [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
b [0.166667, 0.142857, 0.125, 0.111111, 0.1]
```

[playpen](http://is.gd/U1qj6n).

There's various ways this could be optimised, e.g. when fetching in `First`, only buffer the left-over `B` if a `Second` handle exists.

<sup>1</sup> If you were looking to run them in separate threads just replace the `RefCell` with a [`Mutex`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html) and the `Rc` with an [`Arc`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html), and add the necessary bounds.