# What are the drawbacks of a group_by iterator adaptor

Tags: group-by, iterator, rust

Imagine an iterator over `(key,value)` pairs where the key isn't unique. What downsides would there be to creating an iterator adapter that splits the iterator into many "streams" which any subsequent adapters would operate on?

I'm imagining something where the following pseudocode would return the 10th element for each key:

```
let res: HashMap<key_type, value_type> =
    my_input_stream.iter()
    .group_by(|(key, value)| key)
    .skip(9)
    .take(1)
    .collect();
```

I'm aware of itertools' `group_by`, but it only works for consecutive groups. I am talking about something that would work when the groups are nonconsecutive as well. I think my idea could run into a lot of problems with the design of Rust's iterators.

To be more concrete, the two implementations that I am considering are:

- an iterator that produces many iterators, somewhat akin to `unzip`.
  This has the problem that you probably couldn't chain any more
  adapters after that point. (similar to: [Splitting Iterator<(A,B)> into Iterator<A> and Iterator<B>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25586681/splitting-iteratora-b-into-iteratora-and-iteratorb))
- an iterator that you call `next` with a group key argument.
  That would potentially have to buffer a lot of data and breaks the
  signature of `next`.

Comment: This sounds off-topic. Do you have any *concrete* problems or are you just brainstorming? FWIW, [it exists](http://bluss.github.io/rust-itertools/doc/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.group_by), [twice](http://bluss.github.io/rust-itertools/doc/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.group_by_lazy).